# Pass Session Cookie in URL Header

Tags: android, session-cookies, android-xml, sessionid, http-redirect

I have successfully logged in and received Session Cookie. Now I need to pass this session cookie in Header of another URL to get more information. The URL: http://myexperiment.org.uk/whoami.xml then should redirect itself to another URL which produces XML tree. I need to use this XML to get user id information (which is a tree node).

Here is my code.

```
    Log.d("Session Cookie: ", cookieValue);

    URL urlWhoAmI = new URL("http://www.myexperiment.org/whoami.xml");

    connection1 = (HttpURLConnection) urlWhoAmI.openConnection();
    connection1.setRequestProperty("Set-Cookie", cookieValue);
    connection1.connect();

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(urlWhoAmI.openStream()));
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    NodeList nodeList1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("user");

    for(int i=0; i < nodeList1.getLength(); i++)
    {
        Node node = nodeList1.item(i);

        //For user id
        Element firstElement = (Element) node;
        NodeList nameList = firstElement.getElementsByTagName("id");

        Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
        nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();

        String userID = nameList.item(0).getNodeValue();
        Log.d("User ID: ", userID);
    }
```

When I do debug, I get the java.io.FileNotFoundException for the url.

Hope someone can help here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using Set-Cookie, when you should be using just Cookie for the header field. Set-Cookie is for server responses, Cookie is for client requests.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields